# How can I order a hued boxplot by difference in means?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I am hoping to use a boxplot (currently through seaborn) to display difference between two conditions. It would benefit from ordering, however, it feels that the most value would come from ordering by difference in means. My idea is to calculate the difference in means in a separate dataframe and then try to use the column ordering in that re-ordered dataframe to influence the

```
#custom palette
my_pal = {"Year A": "#e42628", "Year B": "#377db6"}

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))
ax = sns.boxplot(x='variable', y="value", hue="Condition", showmeans=True, data=df, palette=my_pal, meanprops={"marker":"s","markerfacecolor":"white", "markeredgecolor":"black"})
plt.ylabel("Temperature (\xb0C)")
plt.xlabel("Room")
```

I've calculated means then difference using:

```
# calculate means based on condition    
meansofgroups = df.groupby('Condition').mean()
# calculate difference in means and then order
diff = meansofgroups.diff() 
# convert all values to positive
diff.abs()
# order values in descending order
diff.T.sort_values('Year B', ascending=False).T
```

Which gives

```
          E         D           G           I       B           etc.
Condition                               
Year A    NaN       NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         etc.
Year B    3.213795  2.473751    1.802886    0.9225  0.527404    etc.
```

However, I'm not sure how to use this new dataframe with columns ordered to influence my boxplot ordering? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it! However, more pythonic methods much appreciated!

```
# calculate means based on condition    
meansofgroups = df.groupby('Condition').mean()
# calculate difference in means and then order
diff = meansofgroups.diff() 
# convert all values to positive
diff2 = diff.abs()
# order values in descending order
diffordered = diff2.T.sort_values('Year B', ascending=False).T    
# Reset the index to retain the condition column
diffordered2 = diffordered.reset_index()
# Sort old dataframe using new order
df_new = df[diffordered2.columns]
# Dataframe for plotting
df_new_melt = df_new.melt(id_vars=['Condition'])
```

Then 'df_new_melt' can be used within the boxplot to create:

[image]